# Calculus II: Monotonic Sequence Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Monotonic Sequence Theorem: Every bounded, monotonic sequence is convergent.
>
> The proof of this theorem is based on the Completeness Axiom for the set R of real numbers, which says that if S is a nonempty set of real numbers that has an upper bound M (x < M for all x in S), then S has a least upper bound b. (This means that b is an upper bound for S, but if M is any other upper bound, then b < M.) The Completeness Axiom is an expression of the fact that there is no gap or hole in the real number line.

I think this is referring to the idea that if our sequence is (0.5)^n, and we are not sure what its smallest value is, we say that the smallest value (M) is equal to 0 (because we know we cannot have any negative values), but there may be a “least lower bound” b which is greater than 0 but a number that the sequence converges to. This is a bad example because we know that that sequence converges to 0, but is the idea right? If so, what is an example of b and M? Why is this relevant?

Comment: For your example the sequence is bounded below by $0$ and what we need here is not upper bounds but rather lowers bounds and *greatest lower bound*. It can be proved in this case that the greatest lower bound is $0$ and sequence converges to it.

Comment: Also your description of completeness axioms requires minor edit. You need to replace the $<$ with $\leq$ everywhere.

Comment: You should try to prove that an increasing sequence which is bounded above converges to its least upper bound. And a decreasing sequence which is bounded below converges to its greatest lower bound. The proofs are easy because the hard part is the existence of least upper bound (and greatest lower bound) which comes for free if we use axiomatic approach to real numbers.

Comment: A better example would be to consider the simple sequence $1-(1/n)$ which is bounded above. Here least upper bound $M=1$ and any number greater than or equal to $1$ fits in the role of $b$.

Comment: I do not understand why the concepts of greatest lower bound or least upper bound are relevant -- is there an example where the sequence is thought to converge to M, but in fact converges to its greatest lower bound / least upper bound (or b, in terms of the notation in my book)?

Comment: How do you know that some sequence converges? The fact that a sequence is monotone and bounded guarantees convergence. This is not obvious. Try the harder example $(1+(1/n))^{n}$ where we don't know if the sequence is convergent.

Comment: It is quite obvious that the sequence in your fourth comment converges to M = 1. What is the purpose of involving a potential least upper bound, in this case?

Comment: Please check my last comment where things are not obvious and the relevance of these concepts can be appreciated.

Comment: Or you may play with the sequence $n(2^{1/n}-1)$. Here also it is not obvious that the sequence converges.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I tried using mathematical induction to both prove it is monotone (by trying to show that $a_{k+2} > a_{k+1)$ and to show that $a_{k} < 3$, but failed at both tasks. I didn't get very far with showing that the sequence is monotone, but got to $a_{k+1} > (4/3)^{a_{k}}$ in trying to show that the upper bound is M. I do not know how to continue, nor how incorporating the concept of least upper bound will help. Could you kindly point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Ok the idea is simple. Via binomial theorem $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=1 +1 +\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}+\dfrac{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!}+\cdots$$ after some simplification (check this) and there are $(n+1)$ on right. As $n$ increases each term increases and number of terms also increases. Thus the sequence is increasing. And then you can show that it is less than $$1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$$ which is further less than $$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\cdots=3$$ (via sum of infinite GP).

Comment: Thus for this sequence $M=3$ is upper bound and sequence converges to the least upper bound which is popularly denoted by the symbol $e$. It can be proved that this $e<3$. This is how the famous number $e$ is born.